# why can a camera reformat my microsd drive but not DiskPart?

Tags: windows-10, diskpart, write-protect

I can not delete data from the directory of my micro-sd card. i tried removing read only protections using diskpart, which said this was completed succesfully however did not change anything.

using diskpart i tried to use clean, which failed giving me an:

```
DiskPart has encountered an error: the request could not be performed because an I/O device error
```

again using diskpart, i try deleting the disk and it says i am not allowed to delete the disk.

using regedit i changed writ3e protect to '0', rebooted, but again did not change anything.

now i have read a plethura of answers of similar questions here, most of which conclude the drive is damaged, however the disk IS able to be reformatted.

i use the disk in my cameras, and in the camera i am able to delete photos, videos, and in my gopro i am able to reformat the drive. why am i able to perform all of these actions in camera, incuding reformating but not from command line?

is there a utility (windows or linux) that is able to circumvent whatever is preventing me from reformating/removing write protections at the diskpart level?

addendum: one of the first things i used this disk for, and hence forth have had this problem, was installing a bootable linux distro to the sd card, that i later used to install the distro on another computer. is there a possibility that could have been part of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I often get this kind of problem. On Linux I use dd to wipe the first few sectors which will get rid of any partition or boot sectors. It has been a while since I used windows but I found some information here https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-use-dd-for-windows-to-make-a-bootable-usb
be VERY careful to make sure you are using the correct drive. I have destroyed a hard drive once. This is what I type on Linux

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1k count=2048 status=progress;sync
```

where you replace x with the drive letter of the USB. Again on linux typing lsblk will list the drives. Be careful

Comment: sorry, i changed the title of my question, if you can address it now

Comment: Format only erases a few sectors on the SD card, so it does not mean that all sectors are good. On windows there is a tool called H2testw which I believe does this. Go through the entire SD card and see if it finds any errors